# Cannot fill out heap despite adding elements to Java HashMap

Tags: java, android, security, out-of-memory, heap-memory

I am working on a very simple attack on a Java program. Let's say that someone made a for loop that computes a value (from a pre existing one) and stores in it in a HashMap. This iterates up until a certain value that I can determine.

I am not sure about the amount of detail I can reveal, because of external constraints. Anyway, this is the equivalent code:

```java
/**
  * key is a PublicKey object 
  * value is a byte[], a member of the class
  * parameter is an int, representing the number of times
  * a new value must be generated
  */
void doSomethingAfterComputingValues(int parameter) {
  for (int i = N; i < parameter; i++) {
    myMap.get(key).put(i,value);      //the map is a map of maps
    value = getNextValue();
  }
  
  N = parameter+1;

  workWithCurrentValue();
```

At this point, I execute this function multiple times, providing a large `parameter` each time.

```java
doSomethingAfterComputingValues(200000)
doSomethingAfterComputingValues(400000)
```

Note that this may only be done once. I do it multiple times simply because there used to be a constraint on a maximum size of `parameter - N`.

The map is not touched outside of these lines, and I checked that it actually increases in side (which the inner map actually does).

What I would expect is for the heap to fill up completely in little time, thus returning a java.lang.OutOfMemoryError.
However, this does not seem to be the case. On the contrary, even with 32M+ entries in the table, the size of the heap seems to be pretty static. I cannot see the reason of this.

It may be worth pointing out that I am running the code with junit on Android Studio.

Is there anything I am missing?

EDIT: I am providing a piece of code that should make everything a bit more clear. Tell me if this is enough, or should include more.

Comment: `myVal = parameter`, doesn't this mean the loop is never entered?

Comment: Are your keys different? What type of object is value?

Comment: Obviously the code above is not Sufficient.
A possible reason why this might happen is if you are making new instances of the class that has this map as it's property. You would be unknowingly making a new dictionary each time perhaps. Make sure it is static. Also if it's something simple like that you can start out by putting a low max mem parameter on a laptop/desktop and running it with the java command before trying it on android.

Comment: I added some more infos, it will hopefully be easier to understand now. I do not think I am creating any new instance, as the size actually increases.